# macOS SDK11 / ARM64: statfs64 / f_mntonname

Tags: macos, xcode12, mount-point, apple-m1

I am using the function `statfs64` to obtain the mount point from a path on macOS via property `f_mntonname`.
This works fine when building against the SDK 10.x for the architecture x86_64.

However, when building for arm64 (and SDK 11), the method is not available.

I can use `statfs` as fallback which seems to be available, but this has limits to the path length.

I know there is the `NSFileManager`-API (`attributesOfFileSystemForPath`), but unfortunately there is no property for the mount path.

Does anyone know how to to this on the new SDK/Platform?

Thank you and regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`statfs64` and `fstatfs64` have been deprecated since macOS 10.6 in favour of "versioned symbols".

If you're building for macOS 10.6 or higher, simply switch to `statfs` and `fstatfs`, and add this at the top of your source files (before the includes):

```
#define _DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE
```

Or add a compiler flag, if changing many source files is too tedious:

```
-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE
```

For arm64 targets, this is already set, so it has no effect.
For x86_64 targets, this causes the linker to emit a dependency on `_statfs$INODE64` (which is equivalent to `_statfs64`) rather than `_statfs`.

If your x86_64 slice does indeed need to support macOS 10.5, then you'll have to resort to some preprocessing:

```
#define _DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE
#if __ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__ < 1060
    #define STATFS statfs64
    #define FSTATFS fstatfs64
#else
    #define STATFS statfs
    #define FSTATFS fstatfs
#endif
```

And if you need to support macOS 10.4 or lower, you're out of luck anyway because there is no 64-bit inode support back there.